# problem when i Published my app on google

Tags: android-security

Security alert

Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys. Please see this Google Help Centre article for details.

Vulnerable locations:

com.onesignal.PushRegistratorFCM->getApiKey
Affects APK version 6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O35tQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a false positive and can be safely ignored. OneSignal is releasing SDK updates to prevent this warning in the future. You can find more details in this thread. https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/970